# finding workbook name

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

The macro file's name is sample1.xlsx. Now, this macro is executed from file sample2.xlsx. How to retrieve the path of sample2.xlsx file using the macro code written inside the file sample1.xlsx?

Comment: If it's the active workbook when invoking the macro, just use `activeworkbook.path` or `activeworkbook.fullname`

Comment: `xlsx` files cannot contain macros. Files containing macros must be saved as `xlsm` or `xlsb`. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

High

I can’t comment so I put it here…

If both workbooks are open, the workbooks collection object of open files will let you reference any workbook. So another way is like

```
Sub Geh_tits_Path()
Dim Parf As String
 Let Parf = Workbooks("sample2.xlsx").Path
End Sub
```

But along the lines of like what Peh said, when you  save the workbook sample1.xlsx , any written macro wont be saved. So if you then close and open workbook sample1.xlsx , the macro will not be there.

Alan